# Is "motionless" an adverb or adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I am reading Charlotte's Web with my daughter. I am glad to be reading E. B. White's book. We pay close attention to the construction of sentences so that we can learn from such exemplary writing. We are reading the 60th anniversary edition.

One sentence read,

> The sheep lay motionless.

and after a while she asked whether it should be "The sheep lay *motionlessly*". We reasoned that since the word is telling us more about the sheep's action, we should choose an *adverb*.

We checked Merriam-Webster's dictionary and dictionary.com and they both defined *motionlessly* as the adverb, keeping *motionless* only as an adjective.

Was *motionless* once used as an adverb as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The function of "young"in these sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186159/the-function-of-youngin-these-sentence) (including _He died young._) It's a depictive construction, using an adjective after a link-like verb. _The man felt happy_.

Comment: [*I feel bad*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20412/i-feel-bad-for-you-versus-i-feel-badly-for-you) about its usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! I am not yet sure, but you may be right. In fact, I just checked the entry for _lie_ at m-w: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie and they say _lie motionless_. So, I guess you are right.