# What is the usage of adjectives directly after a non-copular verb (phrase) called?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, copular-verbs

Sometimes adjectives can be placed directly after a non-copular verb or verb phrase:

> We would *swim naked* every day.
>
> They *got married young*.
>
> He *walked barefoot* on the still charring coal.

In these examples, the complementary adjectives and the verbs concur, but the verbs themselves are not the copulae that connect the adjectives to the subjects. Instead, the verbs express actions or states that are independent of the adjectives. Essentially these examples could be paraphrased as follows:

> We would swim every day and we would be naked doing so.
>
> They got married and they were young doing so.
>
> He walked on the still charring coal and he was barefoot doing so.

What is this usage called, in grammatical terms? I'd like to learn more about the thinking and rules behind this sort of construction.

Comment: The adjective "naked" is predicative, but since it is optional it is best analysed as a depictive adjunct rather than a complement. The label 'predicative adjunct' is appropriate here because the predicative/non-predicative contrast cuts across that between complements and adjuncts. The same analysis applies to your other examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The function of "young"in these sentences ... _He died young....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186159/the-function-of-youngin-these-sentence). The subject-orientated depictive usage.

Comment: Have a look at https://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/s07/events/wechsler05.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The term 'secondary predicate' is a very general term, whereas the term 'predicative adjunct' is spot-on and more precise. In a tree diagram, the function of the adjectives in your examples would be labelled adjuncts.                                                                                                                                                             – BillJ

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BillJ's comment, I Googled "predicative adjunct" and got this [this](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Predicative_adjunct) among the results, which suggests "secondary predicate". So "[secondary predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate)" it is, then.

Comment: The term 'secondary predicate' is a very general term, whereas the term 'predicative adjunct' is spot-on and more precise. In a tree diagram, the function of the adjectives in your examples would be labelled adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ Apart from “married”, which is a Complement.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Of course, but we're not talking about "married" here, but about "young" which is just as much an adjective functioning as an adjunct as "naked" and "barefoot" are.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, yes. Wasn't thinking straight.