# Is "him" the direct object in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> His ex-girlfriend considered him a man scorned.

Is "him" the direct object with "a man scorned" acting as the objective complement? Also, is it appropriate to place "scorned" after "man."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can verbal passives be used in secondary predicates?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262153/when-can-verbal-passives-be-used-in-secondary-predicates): << "I prefer/eat my food salted/hot" is an object-orientated depictive construction. >> In your example, 'him' is certainly the DO with 'a man scorned' the object-orientated object complement. // The postnominal positioning of the adjective is literary in style, avveptable in such registers.

Comment: Please do some research before posting. Thank you. Also, this should be on ELL, not here.

Comment: Lambie, what is ELL? And how does one access it? Thank you.