# What part of a sentence is that word in these kind of sentences

Tags: sentence-patterns

hi and thanks for reading.
I can find many sentences which are very simple but i can't assign all of the words with the correct part of a sentence.
What i mean is, in sentences such as:

1. She washed it *clean*.
2. He shot him *dead*.
3. They bled me *dry*

So as i already mentioned, these are fairly simple sentences that follows the simple
Subject Verb Object paradigm, but what puzzles me is the adjective that follows 
Are they simply an object complement as in: They elected him president ?
I appreciate the help.

Comment: They are adjectives. Here, they describe the final state of the referent and the constructions are called resultative. Contrast a depictive construction (He was being eaten alive.) Some would call this type of construction secondary predication.

Comment: Better answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111062/can-object-complements-make-any-difference-to-sentences