# What is the structure of 'Shot dead'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"Boss shot dead his girl friend." Please elaborate the structure of the sentence. Can I replace "shot" with any other word, like stabbed,  poisoned or beat?

Comment: possible duplicate: read adjective where I said adverb,to please nitpickers; :) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328758/how-to-analyse-shot-dead

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shot%20dead%2C%20stabbed%20dead%2C%20poisoned%20dead%2C%20beat%20dead%2C%20beaten%20dead&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshot%20dead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstabbed%20dead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoisoned%20dead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeat%20dead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeaten%20dead%3B%2Cc0#), *stabbed*, *poisoned*, *beat*, and *beaten* dead are all virtually non-existent, compared to *shot dead*.  While they are all equally grammatically correct, only ***shot dead*** is idiomatic.

As to what part of speech ***hard*** is in this instance, I suspect (but cannot say authoritatively) that it's acting as an adverb.  Other, similar constructions would include:

> *He was hit **hard**.*
>   *She ran **quickly**.*
>   *He spoke **softly**.*